# Openscad Rendering Freeze

Tags: 3d, rendering, openscad

I wrote an openscad code. It was an easy short code. I can compile it very fast. .however, when I tried to render it, it takes more than a half hour. At the 99 percent, it doesn't end and continues working. Can anyone help me about it?

Code I am using;

```
     translate([0,0,1]) 
waveform(3); 
 translate([0,0,2]) 
waveform(3.001); 
 translate([0,0,3]) 
waveform(3.002); 
 translate([0,0,4]) 
waveform(3.001); 
 translate([0,0,5]) 
waveform(3.001); 
 translate([0,0,6]) 
waveform(3.002); 
 translate([0,0,7]) 
waveform(3); 
 translate([0,0,8]) 
waveform(3.003); 
 translate([0,0,9]) 
waveform(3.002); 
 translate([0,0,10]) 
waveform(3.001); 
 translate([0,0,11]) 
waveform(3.001); 
 translate([0,0,12]) 
waveform(3.001); 
 translate([0,0,13]) 
waveform(3.004); 
 translate([0,0,14]) 
waveform(3.001); 
 translate([0,0,15]) 
waveform(3.002); 
 translate([0,0,16]) 
waveform(3.002); 
 translate([0,0,17]) 
waveform(3); 
 translate([0,0,18]) 
waveform(3.001); 
 translate([0,0,19]) 
waveform(3); 
 translate([0,0,20]) 
waveform(3.001); 
 translate([0,0,21]) 
waveform(3.008); 
 translate([0,0,22]) 
waveform(3.031); 
 translate([0,0,23]) 
waveform(3.023); 
 translate([0,0,24]) 
waveform(3.049); 
 translate([0,0,25]) 
waveform(3.088); 
 translate([0,0,26]) 
waveform(3.14); 
 translate([0,0,27]) 
waveform(3.106); 
 translate([0,0,28]) 
waveform(3.181); 
 translate([0,0,29]) 
waveform(3.166); 
 translate([0,0,30]) 
waveform(3.106); 
 translate([0,0,31]) 
waveform(3.098); 
 translate([0,0,32]) 
waveform(3.104); 
 translate([0,0,33]) 
waveform(3.107); 
 translate([0,0,34]) 
waveform(3.055); 
 translate([0,0,35]) 
waveform(3.02); 
 translate([0,0,36]) 
waveform(3.018); 
 translate([0,0,37]) 
waveform(3.011); 
 translate([0,0,38]) 
waveform(3.016); 
 translate([0,0,39]) 
waveform(3.018); 
 translate([0,0,40]) 
waveform(3.009); 
 translate([0,0,41]) 
waveform(3.006); 
 translate([0,0,42]) 
waveform(3.004); 
 translate([0,0,43]) 
waveform(3.003); 
 translate([0,0,44]) 
waveform(3.004); 
 translate([0,0,45]) 
waveform(3.003); 
 translate([0,0,46]) 
waveform(3.005); 
 translate([0,0,47]) 
waveform(3.002); 
 translate([0,0,48]) 
waveform(3.002); 
 translate([0,0,49]) 
waveform(3.01); 
 translate([0,0,50]) 
waveform(3.112); 
 translate([0,0,51]) 
waveform(4.334); 
 translate([0,0,52]) 
waveform(8.523); 
 translate([0,0,53]) 
waveform(9.894); 
 translate([0,0,54]) 
waveform(10.015); 
 translate([0,0,55]) 
waveform(12.263); 
 translate([0,0,56]) 
waveform(11.903); 
 translate([0,0,57]) 
waveform(11.737); 
 translate([0,0,58]) 
waveform(11.791); 
 translate([0,0,59]) 
waveform(8.681); 
 translate([0,0,60]) 
waveform(7.113); 
 translate([0,0,61]) 
waveform(7.799); 
 translate([0,0,62]) 
waveform(6.152); 
 translate([0,0,63]) 
waveform(7.055); 
 translate([0,0,64]) 
waveform(7.184); 
 translate([0,0,65]) 
waveform(7.344); 
 translate([0,0,66]) 
waveform(9.483); 
 translate([0,0,67]) 
waveform(7.807); 
 translate([0,0,68]) 
waveform(10.2); 
 translate([0,0,69]) 
waveform(7.023); 
 translate([0,0,70]) 
waveform(8.276); 
 translate([0,0,71]) 
waveform(7.361); 
 translate([0,0,72]) 
waveform(9.759); 
 translate([0,0,73]) 
waveform(8.454); 
 translate([0,0,74]) 
waveform(8.494); 
 translate([0,0,75]) 
waveform(7.505); 
 translate([0,0,76]) 
waveform(6.512); 
 translate([0,0,77]) 
waveform(5.61); 
 translate([0,0,78]) 
waveform(4.005); 
 translate([0,0,79]) 
waveform(4.071); 
 translate([0,0,80]) 
waveform(3.718); 
 translate([0,0,81]) 
waveform(4.318); 
 translate([0,0,82]) 
waveform(4.153); 
 translate([0,0,83]) 
waveform(4.429); 
 translate([0,0,84]) 
waveform(3.81); 
 translate([0,0,85]) 
waveform(3.629); 
 translate([0,0,86]) 
waveform(3.428); 
 translate([0,0,87]) 
waveform(3.277); 
 translate([0,0,88]) 
waveform(3.2); 
 translate([0,0,89]) 
waveform(3.203); 
 translate([0,0,90]) 
waveform(3.131); 
 translate([0,0,91]) 
waveform(3.311); 
 translate([0,0,92]) 
waveform(3.386); 
 translate([0,0,93]) 
waveform(5.816); 
 translate([0,0,94]) 
waveform(9.286); 
 translate([0,0,95]) 
waveform(10.809); 
 translate([0,0,96]) 
waveform(11.715); 
 translate([0,0,97]) 
waveform(14.255); 
 translate([0,0,98]) 
waveform(16); 
 translate([0,0,99]) 
waveform(15.714); 
 translate([0,0,100]) 
waveform(9.868); 
 translate([0,0,101]) 
waveform(7.276); 
 translate([0,0,102]) 
waveform(4.541); 
 translate([0,0,103]) 
waveform(4.137); 
 translate([0,0,104]) 
waveform(4.036); 
 translate([0,0,105]) 
waveform(3.527); 
 translate([0,0,106]) 
waveform(3.759); 
 translate([0,0,107]) 
waveform(3.778); 
 translate([0,0,108]) 
waveform(3.425); 
 translate([0,0,109]) 
waveform(4.735); 
 translate([0,0,110]) 
waveform(4.672); 
 translate([0,0,111]) 
waveform(7.273); 
 translate([0,0,112]) 
waveform(6.602); 
 translate([0,0,113]) 
waveform(8.319); 
 translate([0,0,114]) 
waveform(8.125); 
 translate([0,0,115]) 
waveform(7.379); 
 translate([0,0,116]) 
waveform(8.451); 
 translate([0,0,117]) 
waveform(6.174); 
 translate([0,0,118]) 
waveform(5.415); 
 translate([0,0,119]) 
waveform(4.673); 
 translate([0,0,120]) 
waveform(3.947); 
 translate([0,0,121]) 
waveform(4.051); 
 translate([0,0,122]) 
waveform(4.008); 
 translate([0,0,123]) 
waveform(3.768); 
 translate([0,0,124]) 
waveform(3.346); 
 translate([0,0,125]) 
waveform(3.26); 
 translate([0,0,126]) 
waveform(3.172); 
 translate([0,0,127]) 
waveform(3.197); 
 translate([0,0,128]) 
waveform(3.218); 
 translate([0,0,129]) 
waveform(3.207); 
 translate([0,0,130]) 
waveform(3.145); 
 translate([0,0,131]) 
waveform(4.928); 
 translate([0,0,132]) 
waveform(7.679); 
 translate([0,0,133]) 
waveform(7.145); 
 translate([0,0,134]) 
waveform(5.607); 
 translate([0,0,135]) 
waveform(5.616); 
 translate([0,0,136]) 
waveform(5.284); 
 translate([0,0,137]) 
waveform(5.292); 
 translate([0,0,138]) 
waveform(4.516); 
 translate([0,0,139]) 
waveform(4.04); 
 translate([0,0,140]) 
waveform(3.615); 
 translate([0,0,141]) 
waveform(3.408); 
 translate([0,0,142]) 
waveform(3.349); 
 translate([0,0,143]) 
waveform(3.173); 
 translate([0,0,144]) 
waveform(3.231); 
 translate([0,0,145]) 
waveform(3.382); 
 translate([0,0,146]) 
waveform(3.479); 
 translate([0,0,147]) 
waveform(3.545); 
 translate([0,0,148]) 
waveform(3.611); 
 translate([0,0,149]) 
waveform(3.628); 
 translate([0,0,150]) 
waveform(3.488); 
 translate([0,0,151]) 
waveform(3.236); 
 translate([0,0,152]) 
waveform(3.964); 
 translate([0,0,153]) 
waveform(7.194); 
 translate([0,0,154]) 
waveform(8.915); 
 translate([0,0,155]) 
waveform(7.076); 
 translate([0,0,156]) 
waveform(6.897); 
 translate([0,0,157]) 
waveform(7.43); 
 translate([0,0,158]) 
waveform(6.866); 
 translate([0,0,159]) 
waveform(6.294); 
 translate([0,0,160]) 
waveform(6.25); 
 translate([0,0,161]) 
waveform(6.686); 
 translate([0,0,162]) 
waveform(5.242); 
 translate([0,0,163]) 
waveform(3.775); 
 translate([0,0,164]) 
waveform(4.079); 
 translate([0,0,165]) 
waveform(3.834); 
 translate([0,0,166]) 
waveform(3.596); 
 translate([0,0,167]) 
waveform(3.411); 
 translate([0,0,168]) 
waveform(4.507); 
 translate([0,0,169]) 
waveform(5.967); 
 translate([0,0,170]) 
waveform(7.418); 
 translate([0,0,171]) 
waveform(8.791); 
 translate([0,0,172]) 
waveform(6.064); 
 translate([0,0,173]) 
waveform(4.484); 
 translate([0,0,174]) 
waveform(3.53); 
 translate([0,0,175]) 
waveform(3.411); 
 translate([0,0,176]) 
waveform(3.286); 
 translate([0,0,177]) 
waveform(3.446); 
 translate([0,0,178]) 
waveform(3.863); 
 translate([0,0,179]) 
waveform(3.93); 
 translate([0,0,180]) 
waveform(3.984); 
 translate([0,0,181]) 
waveform(4.103); 
 translate([0,0,182]) 
waveform(3.561); 
 translate([0,0,183]) 
waveform(3.317); 
 translate([0,0,184]) 
waveform(5.223); 
 translate([0,0,185]) 
waveform(11.432); 
 translate([0,0,186]) 
waveform(11.407); 
 translate([0,0,187]) 
waveform(9.557); 
 translate([0,0,188]) 
waveform(8.368); 
 translate([0,0,189]) 
waveform(8.685); 
 translate([0,0,190]) 
waveform(8.721); 
 translate([0,0,191]) 
waveform(7.899); 
 translate([0,0,192]) 
waveform(7.535); 
 translate([0,0,193]) 
waveform(7.595); 
 translate([0,0,194]) 
waveform(7.792); 
 translate([0,0,195]) 
waveform(7.756); 
 translate([0,0,196]) 
waveform(7.829); 
 translate([0,0,197]) 
waveform(8.236); 
 translate([0,0,198]) 
waveform(9.736); 
 translate([0,0,199]) 
waveform(9.742); 
 translate([0,0,200]) 
waveform(9.623); 
 translate([0,0,201]) 
waveform(7.755); 
 translate([0,0,202]) 
waveform(5.084); 
 translate([0,0,203]) 
waveform(5.321); 
 translate([0,0,204]) 
waveform(6.031); 
 translate([0,0,205]) 
waveform(5.769); 
 translate([0,0,206]) 
waveform(5.278); 
 translate([0,0,207]) 
waveform(5.452); 
 translate([0,0,208]) 
waveform(5.203); 
 translate([0,0,209]) 
waveform(4.552); 
 translate([0,0,210]) 
waveform(3.942); 
 translate([0,0,211]) 
waveform(3.319); 
 translate([0,0,212]) 
waveform(3.305); 
 translate([0,0,213]) 
waveform(3.186); 
 translate([0,0,214]) 
waveform(3.139); 
 translate([0,0,215]) 
waveform(3.127); 
 translate([0,0,216]) 
waveform(3.083); 
 translate([0,0,217]) 
waveform(3.1); 
 translate([0,0,218]) 
waveform(3.057); 
 translate([0,0,219]) 
waveform(3.064); 
 translate([0,0,220]) 
waveform(3.055); 
 translate([0,0,221]) 
waveform(3.038); 
 translate([0,0,222]) 
waveform(3.044); 
 translate([0,0,223]) 
waveform(3.033); 
 translate([0,0,224]) 
waveform(3.022); 
 translate([0,0,225]) 
waveform(3.018); 
 translate([0,0,226]) 
waveform(3.02); 
 translate([0,0,227]) 
waveform(3.029); 
 translate([0,0,228]) 
waveform(3.014); 
 translate([0,0,229]) 
waveform(3.028); 
 translate([0,0,230]) 
waveform(3.014); 
 translate([0,0,231]) 
waveform(3.011); 
 translate([0,0,232]) 
waveform(3.011); 
 translate([0,0,233]) 
waveform(3.016); 
 translate([0,0,234]) 
waveform(3.008); 
 translate([0,0,235]) 
waveform(3.028); 
 translate([0,0,236]) 
waveform(3.015); 
 translate([0,0,237]) 
waveform(3.013); 
 translate([0,0,238]) 
waveform(3.006); 
 translate([0,0,239]) 
waveform(3.007); 
 translate([0,0,240]) 
waveform(3.008); 
 translate([0,0,241]) 
waveform(3.007); 
 translate([0,0,242]) 
waveform(3.006); 
 translate([0,0,243]) 
waveform(3.012); 
 translate([0,0,244]) 
waveform(3.008); 
 translate([0,0,245]) 
waveform(3.006); 
 translate([0,0,246]) 
waveform(3.004); 
 translate([0,0,247]) 
waveform(3.007); 
 translate([0,0,248]) 
waveform(3.006); 
 translate([0,0,249]) 
waveform(3.009); 
 translate([0,0,250]) 
waveform(3.005); 
 translate([0,0,251]) 
waveform(3.003); 
 translate([0,0,252]) 
waveform(3.005); 
 translate([0,0,253]) 
waveform(3.127); 
 translate([0,0,254]) 
waveform(3.031); 
 translate([0,0,255]) 
waveform(3.013); 
 translate([0,0,256]) 
waveform(3.008); 
 translate([0,0,257]) 
waveform(3.006); 
 translate([0,0,258]) 
waveform(3.011); 
 translate([0,0,259]) 
waveform(3.01); 
 translate([0,0,260]) 
waveform(3.01); 
 translate([0,0,261]) 
waveform(3.008); 





module waveform(radius) {
    $fn = 50;

    hole_radius = 2.000;
    thickness = 1.000;
    round_edges = true;
    bed_gap = 5.000;

    edge_radius = thickness / 2;
    center_radius = radius - edge_radius;

    waveform_center = radius + (bed_gap / 2);

difference(){
    cylinder(r=radius, h=thickness, center=true);
    cylinder(r=1, h=1, center=true);
}

    }
```

Comment: `$fn = 50` is quite high. Make a test with 10.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly encourage you to upgrade to a newer version of OpenSCAD.  I'm running development snapshot 2014.10.02 and it made fairly quick work of this model in F6 mode in under 20 minutes.  You can find the [development snapshots here](http://www.openscad.org/downloads.html#snapshots).

Answer (score 0):

You also be a lot happier if you render it from the command line. A new instance of OpenSCAD will do the hard work in the background.

In OSX/linux you could make a small script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
time /Applications/OpenSCAD.app/Contents/MacOS/OpenSCAD -o ${1%.*}.stl $1 && say -v 'Zarvox' "Conversion of ${1%} finished"
```